# Is $n^2 - n + 1$ prime infinitely often?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, open-problem

It seems that this is an open question, though I haven't been able to find many references pointing to work towards the answer.

I know that $n^2-n+1$ is conjectured to be prime infinitely often by the [Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral#Hardy_and_Littlewood's_Conjecture_F). Moreover, a quick python script shows that about $10$% of the integers up to $n = 100,000$ yield primes under this quadratic, so this happens not infrequently.

Comment: It is conjectured that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. For example, $674^2+1$ is prime. Perhaps this is a good start to proving so for the quadratic?

Comment: The range $0\le n\le 10^8$ produces $\color\red {6\ 456\ 835}$ primes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of [Bunrakovsky's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), which is only known for the degree 1 case - the famous Dirichlet's theorem. Weaker version (idealistic version) of the conjecture is true by the [Chebotarev's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem). For example, in your case, we know that there are infinitely many primes $p$ which splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{3})=\mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)$, and in this case, $p=a^{2}-ab+b^{2}$ for some $a, b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Actually, this holds if and only if $p\equiv 1(mod 3)$ (or $p=3$), which has density $1/2$. 
However, your question is equivalent to whether there are infinitely many prime (or irreducible) elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{3}]$ which has a form of $n+\zeta
_{3}$, and this is an open question.

Comment: (+1) , especially for the additional remark enlightening a partial result